# Why does my symbolic link not work?

Tags: terminal, symlink

I wrote a small [Julia](https://julialang.org/) program:

```
println("Hello world!")
```

I can run Julia from the Terminal:

```
$ /Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia test.jl 
Hello world!
```

To make my life easier, I tried to create a symbolic link to the julia file.
However, it doesn't seem to work!

```
$ sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
$ julia
-bash: julia: command not found
$ type -a julia
-bash: type: julia: not found
```

How do I get my symbolic link to work properly?

What is confusing for me is that `/usr/local/bin/` is in my PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: What does the output of `type -a julia` says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong:
I made a typographical mistake when I was creating the symbolic link!

**WRONG**

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

**CORRECT**

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```

(I was missing the **`julia`** in `.../Resources/julia/bin/...`)

Comment: Then the title of this question should be "Are my glasses on?" which is a question I should ask myself because I didn't see it either .

Answer (score 0):

It's a better idea to add the folder that contains the binary to your `$PATH` instead of creating a link to the file inside `/usr/local/bin`.

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/Applications/Julia-0.6.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin"
```

This way, you don't need to create invidual links for every single file inside the bin folder if you ever want to use them.

You can also add this line to `~/.bash_profile` for it to persist after you close the terminal.